# problem in opening next form on button click

Tags: c#

i've two groups of radio buttons, a drop down list & a submit button..on corresponding selected radio buttons & drop down item i need to open next specific form..
say if i selected in first radio button say Existing user(of website) and in another say individual, and in drop down if i select residential property then it should open a residential form,if i select commercial property then it should open a commercial form etc.
can u please help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is button and on click of this button you have open either of the forms..  You can add a `Button_Click()` event handler and in there check

Psuedo-code looks like this

```
if(radioButton1.selected && dropdownList.SelectedValue =="Residential")  
{ 
    frmResidential frmRes = new frmResidential();
    frmRes.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code example in previous post will work for window forms. Looks like you have Web Application. In this case you can use Response.Redirect method to go to different web form.

`if(radioButton1.selected && dropdownList.SelectedValue =="Residential") 
       {
          Response.Redirect("YouPage.aspx");
       }`